# How to create a composite pojo using application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Composite pojo like below

```
class Employee {  
   String name;
   String department;
   Address address;
} 

class Address {
   String Street;
   String HouseNo;
   String postCode;
}
```

Is there a way to create properties in `application.yml` file and at the start of application I can have a list of beans for Employee?

Comment: Sure, no problem! *All* covered by [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties)! *But*: i would refuse to do that (create beans at app start! (for more than 2-99 employees;) + maintain private data in source control (..where `application.yaml|.properties` normally reside))

Comment: I wonder, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.  Spring uses configuration properties to handle this.  Here's an example given your model.

Ensure that your model has the appropriate getters/setters defined.

```
@Data
public class Employee {
    String name;
    String department;
    Address address;
}

@Data
public class Address {
    String Street;
    String HouseNo;
    String postCode;
}
```

Add the configuration processor dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

On your main class that's annotated as `@SpringBootApplication`, add the annotation to enable configuration property processing.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(EmployeeConfigurer.class)
```

Create the class that will load the properties and expose them as a Bean

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
public class EmployeeConfigurer {
    @Setter
    private List<Employee> employees;


    @Bean
    public List<Employee> employees() {
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Add your employees to your yaml

```
  application:
    employees:
      -
        name: Lane
        department: Mail
        address:
          Street: Elm
          HouseNo: 12
          PostCode: 60012
      -
        name: Bob
        department: Marketing
        address:
          Street: Main
          HouseNo: 42
          PostCode: 61112
```

Now you have a bean that's a `List<Employee>` that you can inject anywhere you want.  I would reiterate the point made in the comments, you should absolutely consider loading these from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what you're trying to achieve. You have a Composite class that consists of an `Employee` and an `Address`. You want to create a list of `Employee` objects with their corresponding `Address` objects from a `yaml` configuration file.

To do this, you'll need to define your yaml properties in a specific way that matches the structure of your Composite class. Here's an example of what your yaml file could look like:

```
employees:
  - name: John Doe
    department: Sales
    address:
      street: 123 Main St
      houseNo: 4A
      postCode: 12345
  - name: Jane Smith
    department: Marketing
    address:
      street: 456 Elm St
      houseNo: 10B
      postCode: 67890
```

In this yaml file, you have a property called `employees`, which is a list of `Employee` objects. Each `Employee` object has a `name`, `department`, and an `address` object. The `address` object also has its own `street`, `houseNo`, and `postCode` properties.

To load this yaml file at the start of the application, you'll need to create a configuration class that maps the yaml properties to a list of `Employee` objects. Here's an example of what that configuration class could look like:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "employees")
public class EmployeeConfig {
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }

    public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}
```

In this configuration class, we use the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to specify the prefix of our yaml properties, which is `employees`. We also have a field called `employeeList` of type `List<Employee>`, which will be populated with the yaml properties at startup.

To use this `EmployeeConfig` class in other parts of your application, you can simply inject it as a dependency. For example, you could create a `RestController` that returns the list of `Employee` objects as JSON:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeConfig employeeConfig;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeConfig employeeConfig) {
        this.employeeConfig = employeeConfig;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employeeConfig.getEmployeeList();
    }
}
```

In this `RestController`, we inject the `EmployeeConfig` class as a dependency in the constructor. We then create a `GET` endpoint that returns the list of `Employee` objects. When this endpoint is hit, Spring Boot will automatically populate the `employeeConfig` field with the yaml properties and return the list of `Employee` objects.